# How to fix Service response is missing Install Referrer install timestamp

Tags: cordova, mobile, cordova-plugins

Im currently using the latest version of cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics 4.3.0/4.2.0 and cordova-support-google-services 1.4.0.

Error is

> 2020-05-05 17:50:46.102 2414-4923/? E/FA-SVC: Service response is missing Install Referrer install timestamp.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Same issue here, cannot find any information about this particular log. It's definitely not about the cordova itself, as I'm using native Kotlin implementation of installreferrer and same log appears.